# Create a HTML page by clicking a JS powered button

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, onclick

I was just wondering if it is possible to use a JS powered button to open a webpage created by the javascript, when clicked.
A button like this:

```html
<button onclick="(open new created webpage pretty please)!">This one!</button>
```

If you don't understand what I'm saying:
https://jsfiddle.net/fWxH3/3/

Also, I'm not sure but I think I need to use PHP, but I have no idea how.

**Edit**
It's been a few months since I posted this question, and since then I have learnt **AJAX** and **PHP**, which has allowed me to accomplish this task. Thanks to **Pete** for suggesting this to me.

Comment: have a search for ajax

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: The link you have given us shows the use of an anchor tag `<a>` to open another page.  The `href` attribute is the page you want to open.  Why not just do that?  If you *do* want a button then just use this... `<button onclick="location.href='target1.html'">This one!</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Add the URL on button click like this. It will open the requested page in new window

```
<button class="button" onClick="window.open('http://www.example.com');"> Click here</button>
```

Comment: I don't think he wants a new window.  The example he gave, in jsfiddle, shows just a regular link.  I think more clarity is needed before you can answer.